# how to find process.env.PORT port number in heroku?

Tags: rest, heroku, server, port, iot

I need to post json data from a IOT device to the server api endpoint. But it requires the port number. How can i find a port number for **process.env.PORT** in **heroku**?

Comment: did you try with 443 which is the port for https ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know that port number.
Within the process, Heroku requires you to bind that process. But their [router](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing) will expose ports 80 and 443 and route requests properly to the process(es) running your app.

In order words: you bind to $PORT in a single process. Heroku's router binds to 80 and 443, and routes to one of many processes (or dynos).

All you have to do is make a request to `your-app-name.herokuapp.com`.